Wrongly counting the number of discontinuities of a function with an inbuilt limit
Plot the given function for $x>0$:$$f(x)=\lim_{n \to ∞} \cos ^n \left(\dfrac{1}{n^x} \right)$$
My attempt: I substituted $n=1/h$ and took the logarithm on both sides;
$$\ln f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\ln \cos (h^x)}{h}$$
Applying L'hopital's rule (the above limit is a $0/0$ form for all $x>0$), I obtained;
$$\ln f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(h^x).x.h^{x-1}}{\cos(h^x)}$$
Here, two cases arise; (I) $x>1$ and (II) $x<1$ (and $f(1)=1$ of course)
In the first case, $f(x)=1$. In the second case, we again obtain a $0/0$ form thus upon applying L'hopital's rule I got;
$$\ln f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\cos(h^x).x^2h^{x-1}}{(x-1)h^{-x}}=0 \implies f(x)=1$$
So it appears as though the function is simply the constant function $f(x)=1$.
However, the answer reported is that $f(x)=0$ when $x<1/2$, $f(x)=1$ when $x>1/2$ and $f(1/2)=e^{-1/2}$.
So, I made a second attempt using series expansions and recognizing that the original limit is of the form $1^∞$. Then, I got the answer as reported. However, what is wrong with the method I used above? Why does L'hopital's rule not account for the discontinuity at $x=1/2$?

Your mistake is in the claim that $$
\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(h^x) x^2 h^{x-1}}{(x-1)h^{-x}} = 0
$$
for all $x<1$. Observe that $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \cos(h^x) = 1$ so this expression simplifies as $$
\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(h^x) x^2 h^{x-1}}{(x-1)h^{-x}} = \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{(x-1)} h^{2x-1}
$$

I can't believe I didn't see that; thank you! Is it okay if I delete the question?

If you like, you can delete it
